# initialize static char const *somevar

Tags: c, pointers, static, constants

I am reading a piece of code, in which there is

```
#include ...

static char const *program_name;

...
int main(int argc, char** argv){
program_name = argv[0];

...
}
```

I am wondering how can the main function assign value to a `const` variable. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The declaration:

```
static char const *program_name;
```

says `program_name` is a (variable) pointer to constant characters.  The pointer can change (so it can be assigned in `main()`), but the string pointed at cannot be changed via this pointer.

Compare and contrast with:

```
static char * const unalterable_pointer = "Hedwig";
```

This is a constant pointer to variable data; the pointer cannot be changed, though if the string it was initialized to point at was not a literal, the string could be modified:

```
static char owls[] = "Pigwidgeon";
static char * const owl_name = owls;

strcpy(owl_name, "Hedwig");

/* owl_name = "Hermes"; */ /* Not allowed */
```

Also compare and contrast with:

```
static char const * const fixed_pointer_to_fixed_data = "Hermes";
```

This is a constant pointer to constant data.

Comment: Thanks for two other examples! Then I guess that  `*program_name` is `const` if declared in the original way, i.e. `static char const *program_name;`. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Correct.  You could not write `*program_name = 'a';` because `program_name` points to constant data; you cannot modify the data via this pointer (though other pointers to the same data may be able to modify it — in this case, you could write `*argv[0] = 'a';` if you wanted to, though I can't think of a good reason for wanting to do so).

Answer (score 8):

`program_name` is a pointer to const char, not a const pointer. The assignment statement assigns a value to the pointer not to the pointee.

Comment: Your answer also makes sense, but I prefer Jonathan's detailed explanation. Still, thanks!